# Grabbing text from a span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code for Javascript using jQuery, and I've been wondering how to fix an element of it.

```
var dataGiven = +$("span.cost-in-usd:first-child").text();
```

However, the span tag is:

```
<span class="cost-in-usd" data-se="product-usd-value">42</span>
```

Is there a way of modifying my code in order for it to recognise `data-se`?

Comment: `$('.cost-in-usd').data('se')` or `$('.cost-in-usd').attr('data-se')` ?

Comment: What do you mean by `recognise`?  Are you trying to get the data value, or use the data attribute in the selector?

Comment: Okay, now I'm more confused. 42 is the text, not the `data-se` value.

Comment: Wow, I confused myself. I want the `data-se` value, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use `data`.

```
   var datase = $('.cost-in-usd').data('se');
```

Some links;

- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/
- [Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4e9TL/)

Comment: Oops, I accidental deleted my comment. But anyway, thanks. I will be able to accept this as the best answer in 9 minutes, and will do so.

Answer (score 0):

The following will return the value of attribute

```
 $('.cost-in-usd').attr('data-se');
```